# read only replica of azure sql database within the same server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, read-only-database

I have the following bicep to create a sql server and sql database:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-02-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: userName
    administratorLoginPassword: password
    administrators: {}
  }

  resource sqlDataBaseOne 'databases@2021-02-01-preview' = {
    name: 'databaseone'
    location: location
    sku: {
      name: 'GP_S_Gen5'
      tier: 'GeneralPurpose'
      family: 'Gen5'
      capacity: 4
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create read only replica of `databaseone` within the same server?

I only see Geo-Replica option on trying to create a replica for which replica is on a different server:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Use read-only replicas to offload read-only query workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out?view=azuresql#verify-that-a-connection-is-to-a-read-only-replica)

The short answer is no.

Why?

> As part of High Availability architecture, each single database,
> elastic pool database, and managed instance in the Premium and
> Business Critical service tier is automatically provisioned with a
> primary read-write replica and one or more secondary read-only
> replicas.
>
> The High Availability architecture of Basic, Standard, and General
> Purpose service tiers does not include any replicas. The read
> scale-out feature is not available in these service tiers. However,
> when using Azure SQL Database, geo-replicas can provide similar
> functionality in these service tiers.

Options you have:

1. If you switch to the Premium and Business Critical tier, you will not connect to the same server for read_only traffic. You will connect to one of the replicas other than the read_write one.
2. As you mentioned, the other option is to set up Replica.
3. Custom solution to a point in time restore in the same server with a different name, but you will not be in sync with the source database.